# Delayed_job ActionMailer caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I currently call a delayed_job (gem delayed_job_mongoid) to send a confirmation email. However, it doesn't seem to use the latest data I'm passing, and instead uses a cached version. See below:

My controller:

```
...
_user.calculate_orders
_user.save
_user.reload
Mailer.delay.order_reported(_user)
...
```

The Mailer

```
class Mailer < Devise::Mailer
  def order_reported(to_user)
    @to_user = to_user
    email_with_name = "#{@to_user.name} <#{@to_user.email}>"
    mail(:to => email_with_name, :subject => "Test email")
  end
end
```

For example, if an attribute `_user.total_orders` = 3 gets updated to 5 and saved. It's correctly reflected in the database, the delayed job DB record contains the updated info of 5, but when email is sent, it uses cached info of 3.

I've also tried calling the method via rails console:

This works and uses the parameter that's passed and updated info

```
Mailer.order_reported(u).deliver
```

This doesn't work and uses cached data

```
Mailer.delay.order_reported(u)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) recently, related to passing in a serialized version of my User object instead of just an ID.

I would refactor slightly to only pass simple objects as parameters in the delayed method. So, you could do this instead:

```
Mailer.delay.order_reported(_user.id)
```

and then update the method to read as follows:

```
class Mailer < Devise::Mailer
  def order_reported(to_user_id)
    @to_user = User.find(to_user_id)
    email_with_name = "#{@to_user.name} <#{@to_user.email}>"
    mail(:to => email_with_name, :subject => "Test email")
  end
end
```

That would ensure you always get a fresh user object when your mailer is actually delivered.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it seems delayed_job still caches the old object. It only seems to reload if I restart the DJ worker. I then tried @to_user = User.find(to_user_id).reload and that seems to work, but isn't that inefficient?

Comment: Nope, since you need to load the object from the database anyways. It will end us as a simple SELECT query that can be cached easily by the database.

Comment: Thanks. It's odd that .find() didn't work but .find().reload does, even though it's a different worker.